# XML with end tag and without it (self-closing tag)

Tags: php, xml

How to differ

```
<bar />
```

and

```
<bar></bar>
```

with php DOMDocument like:

```
<php
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$xml->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><foo><bar /><bar></bar></foo>');
```

Is it possible somewhat?
Thank you

Comment: Why you want to know? If has no children, there is no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<bar/>
```

and

```
<bar></bar>
```

are equivalent in XML.  XML processors will handle them identically, and your software should too.

### Update per comment pressing the point:

As XML, they are equivalent.  As text, they are different.  ***Treat them as text, not XML, if you wish to control this difference that makes no difference to XML.***  Be aware, though, that you're going against the grain.  ***This difference is insignificant at the XML level.***

Comment: I try to ask again, is it possible. How DOMDocument can know, if 'child' (of xml given as string) is <bar /> or <bar></bar>? Thank you