# Specify an XML Closing tag in Java (it auto <Self-Closes/> for empty elements) -or- Syntax to contain child nodes under specified parent branches?

Tags: java, xml, soap, tags

I am having issues trying to force the closing tags of an XML SOAP request since Java is auto-generating self-closing tags. This is causing an issue with containment and results in invalid sub-element errors. The following shows the code used to make the SOAP body in XML. There are several nodes in the "request" that have no values but the server does hold data for. Below shows the output I'm getting and what I need. Today is my first day playing with Java so please explain in super simple terms or better yet, show an example code line. I read a similarly titled post but appears to be in a different language. I appreciate any help.

### Update: On the w3schools website it states:

"*Empty XML Elements* - An alternative syntax can be used for XML elements with no content: instead of writing a book element (with no content) like this: `<book></book>` It can be written like this `<book />` This sort of element syntax is called self-closing."

So, another way to state my request is, how do I prevent the Java compiler from compiling self-closing XML elements to avoid the errors: "Invalid Subelement Worker_Reference-urn:com.workday/bsvc for element Get_Workers_Request (6$16639)". I need to specify where in the tree the element / child node should close as that resolves the issue when I replicate it in other languages such as VB.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//*************** This is the body code *************** ---------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("Get_Workers_Request", "wd", "urn:com.workday/bsvc");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("Request_References", "wd");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("Worker_Reference", "wd");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem3 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("ID", "wd");
    soapBodyElem3.setAttribute("wd:type", "Employee_ID");
    soapBodyElem3.addTextNode("123");



//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//*************** This is what I get *************** ------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

     <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <wd:Get_Workers_Request>
            <wd:Request_References/>
                <wd:Worker_Reference/>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">123</wd:ID>

        </wd:Get_Workers_Request>


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//*************** This is what I need *************** ------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

     <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <wd:Get_Workers_Request>
            <wd:Request_References>
                <wd:Worker_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">123</wd:ID>

                </wd:Worker_Reference>
            </wd:Request_References> 
        </wd:Get_Workers_Request>
```

### Update #2:

This is a copy and paste from Microsoft VB code with the exact changes made and the results from this excerpt. The lack of containment replicates this failure.

```
sEnv = sEnv & "<wd:Request_References>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<wd:Worker_Reference>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<wd:ID wd:type=""Employee_ID"">" & sEmployee_ID & "</wd:ID>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</wd:Worker_Reference>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</wd:Request_References>"
'--------------------------
'Returns value - John Smith
'--------------------------


sEnv = sEnv & "<wd:Request_References/>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<wd:Worker_Reference/>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<wd:ID wd:type=""Employee_ID"">" & sEmployee_ID & "</wd:ID>"
 'sEnv = sEnv & "</wd:Worker_Reference>"
 'sEnv = sEnv & "</wd:Request_References>"
'------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Returns Error - Invalid Subelement ID-urn:com.workday/bsvc for element Get_Workers_Request (6$16639)
'------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you edit or attempt to re-type the "this is what I get" XML ?  Neither what you claim you're getting nor what you claim you need are [**well-formed**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) XML.

Comment: @kjhughes - yes, this is an excerpt I edited to illustrate the issue. The java compiler sees any child node that doesn't have a value associated with it and it appends a forward slash at the end of the child node. If I take a single child entry from my working VB code (for example) and put the '/' at the end <example/>, it fails with an error "Invalid Subelement ID-urn:com.workday/bsvc for element Get_Workers_Request (6$16639)" just like it is now in Java. What I need is the closing tag </example> to be forced to display in Java and in the proper place. Thanks

Comment: on the w3schools website it state for Empty XML Elements - An alternative syntax can be used for XML elements with no content: instead of writing a book element (with no content) like this: <book></book> It can be written like this <book /> This sort of element syntax is called self-closing.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question if you're trying to avoid self-closing elements.  `<book/>` and `<book></book>` are completely equivalent.  XML processors will handle them identically.  Please read the accepted answer to [XML with end tag and without it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27948432/290085).  Thanks.

Comment: @kjhughes - I appreciate the response. It appears to mean the same for an empty end leaf node but when it is tied to a primary branch it fails every time. I have working code that I can run in VB, just tested it right now. As soon as I replace the <book></book> with only <book /> for an empty primary branch, it fails with the same message "Invalid Sub element". Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits precisely that problem.  Thanks.

Comment: @kjhughes - the code I am using is for logging into a secure cloud so without that account, one would not be able to replicate the issue. I have reduced the example body to the bare minimum. If you look at the 2nd example, the only thing I changed was commenting out the </examples> and changed them to self-closing <examples/>. That is the only thing changed. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess I missed one of the numbers to reference when I mentioned it in one of the last replies I tried above. For anyone struggling... here is what fixed it. By referencing `soapBodyElem1` and 2 it moved the closing tags where I needed it. They no longer self-closed the tag on the same line, rather they encapsulated the element needed below them.

```
SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("Get_Workers_Request", "wd", "urn:com.workday/bsvc");
SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("Request_References", "wd");
SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem1.addChildElement("Worker_Reference", "wd");
SOAPElement soapBodyElem3 = soapBodyElem2.addChildElement("ID", "wd");
soapBodyElem3.setAttribute("wd:type", "Employee_ID");
soapBodyElem3.addTextNode("123");
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you force XML to have closing tags?

### You don't.

You are misinterpreting the error.  ***It has nothing to do with self-closing tags.***  `<e></e>` and `<e/>` are completely equivalent in XML.  XML processors will treat each form identically.  You will not get an error with one form but not the other.  If one is right, they're both right.  See also [XML with end tag and without it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27948432/290085)

Look instead toward the actual composition of the elements you're assembling.  Your error message points you in the right direction:

```
Invalid Subelement xxxxxx for element Get_Workers_Request (6$16639)
```

You're adding an `xxxxxx` to `Get_Workers_Request` where you shouldn't be.   (BTW, why in the world would you block that name?)  Besides the useful validation message, check the schema that defines the expected structure for `Get_Workers_Request` for further guidance.

### Regarding update #2

In your update #2 code, the two constructed requests are not even close to being equivalent, and they do not at all support your claim that your trouble stems from the difference between `<e></e>` and `<e/>`:

- In the one that works, `wd:Request_References` ***contains***
  `wd:Worker_Reference`.
- In the one that fails `wd:Request_References` ***precedes***
  `wd:Worker_Reference`.

Even if you learn nothing else from this answer, you'll be ahead if you think, code, and debug in terms of ***element containment*** rather than the ***closing of tags***.

Comment: Thanks @kjhughes, I added Update #2 above which is a copy and paste of my VB code with the exact changes made and the exact output. Please reference and perhaps you can help me identify the issue? Am I missing something?

Comment: regarding update #2 - yup, Exactly!  that is the issue, one contains and the other precedes. Java looks at my request and is "forcing" my request to precede instead of contain. Hence my original question, how do I force the closing tag "after" the items I need to create containment. This request is not to an XML file that has nothing at the root and main branches, but rather a query for a single piece of data out of millions of data points across each main branch of child nodes.

Comment: Just wanted to say a great big thank you @kjhughes as I really do appreciate your taking time to work this issue with me -- I realize at the onset perhaps my original question was vague so it is great having your help further defining it - regarding update #2 - yup, Exactly! that is the issue, one contains and the other precedes. Java looks at my request and is "forcing" my request to precede instead of contain. Hence my original question, how do I force the closing tag "after" the items I need to create containment.

Comment: Sorry, but if agreeing with my remarks regarding update #2 leads you to *hence my original question* (?!), I cannot help you further.  Good luck.

Comment: I'm confused, yes, I agree that I am having a containment issue with XML, but please keep in mind, the question is due to a lack of control over forming the XML because Java is auto forming the closing. Am I asking the wrong question? Is there a trick to Java where Java automatically puts the closing for containment where I need? At the end of the day I stated I am brand new to Java, if someone can please help take my original posted code and make the output look like I need. Why will you not help? Seems an obvious issue I am having you agreed with the problem.

Comment: Is the issue in here somewhere -- SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem. where this last part (soapBodyElem) is supposed to reference some other defined element soapBodyElem1,2,3, etc...?  Then that will auto-generate, I just tried different things and don't see the output. I'm really looking for a solution @kjhughes

Comment: Renamed the question to capture either way of getting the same result

Answer (score 0):

You say that "it" returns an error `Invalid Subelement ID-urn:com.workday/bsvc for element Get_Workers_Request (6$16639)`. But what is "it"? It looks to me like some kind of process that is validating your generated XML against some kind of schema. Without knowing what this validator is or what the schema is, it's hard to be more specific, but I think you are almost certainly barking up the wrong tree by imagining that it's caused by the use of self-closing tags.

Comment: Thanks for the response Michael -  Java looks at my request and is "forcing" my request to precede instead of contain (see preceding updated answer). Hence my original question, how do I force the closing tag "after" the items I need to create containment. This request is not to an XML file that has nothing at the root and main branches, but rather a query for a single piece of data out of millions of data points across each main branch of child nodes